# Implementation of AspectJ example not working

Tags: java, aspectj, junit5

I'm try to implement a simple AspectJ annotation example from https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj. The difference is, that I want to use the annotation at a JUnit TestClass. I googled a while for the solution but don't find the right hint.

Part of my pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            <!--<source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>-->
            <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
            <!--<encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>-->
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>       
</plugins>
```

My Annotation:

```java
package com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Secured {
public boolean isLocked() default false;
}
```

My Aspect:

```
package com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj;

import com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.annotations.Secured;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public final class SecuredMethodAspect {

@Pointcut("@annotation(secured)")
    public void callAt(Secured secured) {
}

@Before("callAt(secured)")
public void around(JoinPoint pjp, Secured secured) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("++++++++test++++++++");
    //return secured.isLocked() ? null : pjp.proceed();
}
}
```

```java
@Secured(isLocked = true)
public class DummyClassTest {

@Test
@Secured(isLocked = true)
public void dummyTest4(){
    log.info("Test 4");
}
}
```

The Advice is mentions to the class annotation, I see it in the logs:

```
CLASSPATH component C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.3.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[INFO] Join point 'staticinitialization(void com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest.<clinit>())' in Type 'com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest' (DummyClassTest.java:23) advised by before advice from 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj.SecuredMethodAspect' (SecuredMethodAspect.java:62)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest.dummyTest3())' in Type 'com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest' (DummyClassTest.java:64) advised by before advice from 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj.SecuredMethodAspect' (SecuredMethodAspect.java:62)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest.dummyTest4())' in Type 'com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest' (DummyClassTest.java:71) advised by before advice from 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj.SecuredMethodAspect' (SecuredMethodAspect.java:62)
[INFO] Join point 'method-call(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.DummyClass.function1())' in Type 'com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest' (DummyClassTest.java:79) advised by before advice from 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj.SecuredMethodAspect' (SecuredMethodAspect.java:62)
[INFO] Join point 'method-call(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.DummyClass.function2())' in Type 'com.mb.mtpp.main.dummy.DummyClassTest' (DummyClassTest.java:80) advised by before advice from 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj.SecuredMethodAspect' (SecuredMethodAspect.java:62)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.DummyClass.function1())' in Type 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.DummyClass' (DummyClass.java:8) advised by before advice from 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj.SecuredMethodAspect' (SecuredMethodAspect.java:62)
[INFO] Join point 'method-execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.DummyClass.function2())' in Type 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.DummyClass' (DummyClass.java:13) advised by before advice from 'com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj.SecuredMethodAspect' (SecuredMethodAspect.java:62)
```

But the log "++++++++test++++++++" is not shown in the console. It executes as the advice is not there. I annotated the class, the testcase and a method as in the example. I tried different settings for my Pointcut but the shown is the best. Then the class is also advised. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: it seems to be the plexus license with ZipException (logs) when I execute the tests on the command line, the expected log is shown. In IntelliJ I get this error. An update to the newest version did not help.

Comment: The solution for the plexus license was simply to remove it. But it doesn't solve my Problem. When I execute in IntelliJ the Advice is not executed. I tried also with IntelliJ ultimate and aspectj plugin. No success

Comment: Welcome to SO. You use AspectJ Maven settings different from the Baeldung tutorial. Maybe you found a example project I posted here and mixed the two. It should work as shown in the tutorial, as far as I can see.  "Programming by copy & paste" without understanding what you are doing, is not such a good idea. Posting incomplete classes and POMs is not helpful either. Nobody can reproduce your problem that way. You did not even explain if your log is from a test run in IDEA or from Maven. In my case, your project (I had to add the missing parts by guessing) works in IDEA, but not in Maven.

Comment: By the way, why are your AspectJ dependencies test-scoped in the POM? Are your annotation + aspect only used in tests, not in application code? Then it would be OK, but not seeing your project's directory structure, I have no way of knowing

Comment: I have solved your problem locally, but before writing an answer I would like to have your feedback first, because I do dislike guessing. I want to understand your situation first and then adjust my answer to it.

Comment: Hi, Somehow I had to start. The Log was from IDE. I wanted to weave at compile time and didn't put this xml from Baeldung for load-time weaving. It's just for JUnit Tests and yes, no application. What exactly I wanted to do is an aspect at class level and execute a function in the testclass with reflections. But this is a later problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sorry, I was busy.* Assuming that your directory layout is like this:

[image: Maven directory layout]

Some sample classes might look like this:

```java
package com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD })
public @interface Secured {
  boolean isLocked() default false;
}
```

```java
package com.mb.mtpp.main.extension;

import com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.annotations.Secured;

public class MyClass {
  @Secured
  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

```java
package com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.aspectj;

import com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.annotations.Secured;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public final class SecuredMethodAspect {
  @Pointcut("@annotation(secured) && execution(* *(..))")
  public void securedMethods(Secured secured) {}

  @Before("securedMethods(secured)")
  public void interceptSecuredMethods(JoinPoint joinPoint, Secured secured) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
  }
}
```

```java
package com.mb.mtpp.main.extension;

import com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.annotations.Secured;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Secured(isLocked = true)
public class MyTest {
  @Test
  @Secured(isLocked = true)
  public void dummyTest4(){
    System.out.println("Test 4");
  }

  @Test
  @Secured(isLocked = true)
  public void dummyTest5(){
    System.out.println("Test 5");
    new MyClass().doSomething();
  }
}
```

Your POM would be:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SO_AJ_AspectNotTriggered_72344739</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
          <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <!--<goal>compile</goal>-->
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Then if you either run `mvn clean test` or simply import the project into IntelliJ IDEA, the log output will be:

```
execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.MyTest.dummyTest4())
Test 4
execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.MyTest.dummyTest5())
Test 5
```

Now if for whatever reason you also want to apply the aspect to the annotated application class, simply

- move the aspect from `src/test/java` to `src/main/java`,
- remove `<scope>test</scope>` from `aspectjrt` and
- uncomment `<goal>compile</goal>`.

Then the console log would be:

```
execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.MyTest.dummyTest4())
Test 4
execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.MyTest.dummyTest5())
Test 5
execution(void com.mb.mtpp.main.extension.MyClass.doSomething())
```

See? Application class `MyClass` also gets intercepted in this case.

---

**Update:** Concerning why it was not working in your own example, that was because your POM was configured in such a way that Maven Compiler Plugin recompiled your classes after the aspects had been woven my AspectJ Maven Plugin. The result was that the aspect information was lost due to overwritten class files.

Comment: I updated the answer, because before I had forgotten to explain why your example was not working.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I tried it and it works